# Determine which fields in other tables feed another table via stored proc

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have just inherited a 93 page long stored procedure and have been tasked to validate where all of the other table's fields that this stored proc populates into a single 70 field table come from. So, the stored proc runs every night and feeds all 70 fields into a singe table from 14 other tables. Honestly, I don't even know where to start on this one besides copying the proc into Notepad++ and manually searching using "from table1" "from table2" etc. We're using **Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proc should never be 93 pages long. Its like a sentence being two pages long. But if you are stuck with it you have two approaches to try to deal with it:

1) Use debug in SSMS and watch as the various columns are updated.

2) Print out the entire proc and underline every update/insert that takes place. Believe it or not this will ultimately be faster.

Or you can look around on Codeplex and other places for something magical before you go back to steps 1 or 2.

If you are in SSMS  and dealing with such a large proc you may find it useful to turn on Line Numbers:

Click on Tools--> Options --> Text Editor --> Transact SQL and click on Display Line Numbers

Comment: Oh, believe me, I know. We've already decided to re-write it. The business logic is being formulated but that won't happen for quite a long time. So, I'm stuck with it for now. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I've been googling a bit and found some information about Change Tracking and Change Data Capture here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.11.sql.aspx#id0110017 Both of which are going to require more research but can either do what I'm looking to do?

Comment: Change tracking and change data capture are wonderful tools to track changes made to tables and are very table-centric. I don't believe you can trap what line of code made a change. What you were asking is where in the code columns are being updated and that will require a bit of work.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of figured that. Wishful thinking.

Comment: The way to do the kind of project is to do a couple (5?) of pages of code at a time. Do a couple of pages, take a break, do some more. Don't leave it for the last minute and have to do a marathon session. Make sure you are doing something other then staring at code. Write, on a page, on a copy of the file or you will go into dreamland. There is no way I can force myself to read 93 pages of code without a break.  I can but I would rather not.

Comment: Believe it or not but there is only one update and one insert in the entire stored proc. It's pulling the data from 14 tables. The hardest part is figuring out what the variables being used are because the person that wrote the script made all of the 70 columns variables.

Comment: Then go with Debug in SSMS. You can set breakpoints and watch as the variables change. The way to eat an elephant is one bite at a time....

Comment: I can't debug. I don't have sysadmin rights. I was thinking about just installing a local instance on my comp and copying all the dependent tables and the proc to it and debugging it that way.

Comment: You either have to use print statements or install SQL Server on your dev machine. Please make sure that its OK to copy tables to your local machine - I once got into trouble doing exactly that and had to delete all the local tables.